# Simple C pointer confusion

Tags: c, pointers

I'm stuck with this question, and need to understand what's going on each line step-by-step. The first two lines I do understand, but the problem comes at line 3 and 4. Also, what's the difference between the two different print statements?

```
int a[] = {11, 22, 33};
int *p = a, *q = a + 1, *r = a + 2;
*p++ = *r--;
*++q = *r--;
--*p; ++*q; --*r;
printf("%d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
printf("%d %d %d", *p, *q, *r);
```

Comment: What part of those lines are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: *"what's the difference between the two different print statements?"* The pointers no longer point to the base element of the arrays.

Comment: What actually is the point of this type of code, apart from chewing gum and asking if it retains the flavour?

Comment: @WeatherVane this is likely an academic question. I've unfortunately seen engineering exams myself where code like this is expected to be understood. It's an unfortunate teaching technique that professors who are out-of-touch with programming tend to use.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I disagree. To maintain/write C code, you need to know common C idioms. See my answer for a very classical example of `s++ = t++`. While no real code would want to do the specific shenanigans of OP's example, *any real C coder should be able to unravel them*.

Comment: @tucuxi I think it's good to instill a solid understanding of order-of-operations, pointer logic, etc. but there's a fine line between teaching the concepts, and presenting completely nonsensical code such as this. I don't find this to be a useful teaching method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to explain what each line does is to expand it into equivalent code that is easier to parse when you are not too familiar with pointers and pre/post increment:

```
// *p++ = *r--; 
*p = *r;  // copies value in r over to p
p = p+1;  // then increments p, so it now points to a+1
r = r-1;  // and decrements r, so it points to a+1 too

// *++q = *r--;
q = q+1;  // q now points to a+2
*q = *r;  // places value at a+1 in a+2
r = r-1;  // decrements r, so it points to a+0

// --*p; ++*q; --*r;
*p = *p-1; // decrements value at p, that is, a+1
*q = *q+1; // increments value at q, that is, a+2
*r = *r+1; // decrements value at r, that is, a+0

// displays values at a+0, a+1, and a+2
printf("%d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2]);

// displays values at a+1, a+2, and a+0
printf("%d %d %d", *p, *q, *r);
```

If the pre increment/decrement is before the *, then you are modifying values at the position pointed by the pointer; if it is after the *, then you are changing where the pointer points to. In the case of post increment/decrement expressions, you need to use parenthesis if you want to modify values: `*p++` changes what `p` points to and evaluates to that value, `(*p)++` changes the value pointed-to by `p`.

As a fun** exercise, the following code, from [The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), copies a zero-terminated string from location `t` to `s`:

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
   while (*s++ = *t++);
}
```

** your idea of fun may differ from K&R's. Use of `strcpy` has been proven to cause buffer overflows and premature baldness - use `strncpy` instead.

Comment: Nice answer - however disagree with the ending `strcpy()/strncpy()` advice.  Without clear explanation/examples, both suffer mis-use

Comment: Explaining proper use of dynamic memory would require a *lot* of space. However, I felt that a minimum warning was warranted

Answer (score 2):

Just track the pointers.

```
int a[] = {11, 22, 33};
int *p = a, *q = a + 1, *r = a + 2;
```

this points `p` at `a[0]`, `q` at `a[1]`, and `r` at `a[2]`

```
*p++ = *r--;
```

this copies from `*r` to `*p` (setting `a[0]` to `33`), then increments `p` and decrements `r` (so both `p` and `r` end up pointing at `a[1]`)

```
*++q = *r--;
```

this increments `q` (moving it to `a[2]`), then copies from `*r` to `*q` (setting `a[2]` to `22`) and finally decrements `r` (making it point at `a[0]`)

```
--*p; ++*q; --*r;
```

This decrements the value pointed at by `p` (making `a[1]` 21), then increments `*q` (making `a[2]` 23), and finally decrements `*r` (making `a[0]` 32)

```
printf("%d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
printf("%d %d %d", *p, *q, *r);
```

These print the 3 values in the array in different orders.

Answer (score 1):

Ok listen carefully :D 
the problem is in the  [pointer arithmetics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm) (see these very good examples)

```
*p++ = *r--;
```

in this line , `p` and `r` CHANGE their values. ++ operator assigns it to `p+1` and then reads value in it which is `22`(`*` this operator reads value on given address. Like "Hey give me what's inside the space where this pointer points to")

```
*++q = *r--;
```

this line is same in character

```
--*p; ++*q; --*r;
```

here pointers don't change but their values do

so in the end `p` `r` and `q` are not pointing the initial addresses
and print results will be different

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained by operator precedence.

Line 3:

```
*p = *r             a={33(p),22(q),33(r)}
p++,r--             a={33,22(p)(q)(r),33}
```

Line 4:

```
q++                 a={33,22(p)(r),33(q)}
*q = *r             a={33,22(p)(r),22(q)}
r--                 a={33(r),22(p),22(q)}
```

Line 5:

```
--*p                a={33(r),21(p),22(q)}
++*q                a={33(r),21(p),23(q)}
--*r                a={32(r),21(p),23(q)}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>`int a[] = {11, 22, 33};                 //` a[0] ← 11, a[1] ← 22, a[2] ← 33

`int *p = a, *q = a + 1, *r = a + 2;     //` p → &a[0], q → &a[1], r → &a[2]

`*p++ = *r--;                            //` a[0] ← 33, p → &a[1], r → &a[1]

`*++q = *r--;                            //` q → &a[2], a[2] ← 22, r → &a[0]

`--*p; ++*q; --*r;                       //` a[1] ← 21, a[2] ← 23, a[0] ← 32

`printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]); //` output is 32 21 23

`printf("%d %d %d\n", *p, *q, *r);       //` output is 21 23 32</kbd>